# get the formatted output

Tags: sql-server-2005

Having data as shown below

```
ItemCode    SalesPrice  PricingLevel
ITEM-000001 451.000000  Barons
ITEM-000001 432.000000  Guild
```

Is there is a way to get the following output:

```
ItemCode      Barons     Guild
ITEM-000001   451        432
```

Comment: How many different PricingLevel do you have? I can see 2 values for PricingLevel (Barons, Guild). Could there be more items in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemCode, 
Sum(Case when PricingLevel = 'Barons' Then SalesPrice else 0 end) as Barons,
Sum(Case when PricingLevel = 'Guild' Then SalesPrice else 0 end) as Guild
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh, I am using your query because i feel it is faster than the above because in your query there is only one select & in above 3 selects so i feel it is better to use your solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this (note: as i dont know your table name, i called it "Items"):

```
SELECT DISTINCT I1.ItemCode, 
       (SELECT SalesPrice FROM Items I2 WHERE I2.ItemCode = I1.ItemCode AND I2.PricingLevel = 'Barons') Barons,
       (SELECT SalesPrice FROM Items I3 WHERE I3.ItemCode = I1.ItemCode AND I3.PricingLevel = 'Guild') Guild
FROM Items I1
```

For not showing the decimal zeros, use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I1.ItemCode, 
       (SELECT CAST(SalesPrice AS DECIMAL(10,0)) FROM Items I2 WHERE I2.ItemCode = I1.ItemCode AND I2.PricingLevel = 'Barons') Barons,
       (SELECT CAST(SalesPrice AS DECIMAL(10,0)) FROM Items I3 WHERE I3.ItemCode = I1.ItemCode AND I3.PricingLevel = 'Guild') Guild
FROM Items I1
```

Comment: Hi Tufo it's working fine, but is it work fine i.e. performance point of view if i am having huge data?

Comment: if you have only those columns, so it'll work fine, it'll be 1 select for the whole table plus 2 for each item, no problem there. But if you'll have more columns, the performance can be a problem. How many PricingLevel registers do you have?

Comment: In that table i am having 15 columns but pricinglevel is fixed

Comment: fine, but how many pricing levels do you have?
a good way for increasing the performance is creating an extra Index in this table for the column "PricingLevel" and after that create a View for this query.

Comment: yes, there is index already in table i am using that query in a view
Thank you very much